How can I filter for email messages sent from any mailing list?
In GMail you can create a filter based on a single mailing list:
list:(<some.mailing.list>)

And also for multiple lists:
list:({ <some.mailing.list> <another.mailing.list> })

But, is there  a way to specify any (all) mailing lists?
Something like:
list:({ * }) 


Unfortunately Gmail doesn't support wildcards.
The closest I can suggest for what you are asking, is to use the following search term in the "Has the words" field of the search options, or in the search box:
unsubscribe

You will however get some false positives if that word is mentioned in a message outside the context of an Unsubscribe link.
